# how to know the customer is creating or updating in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, php-5.4

I have a validations for customers. So, these validations or depending on Customer creating and updating.

Please let me know there is any chances to know weather there is customer is creating(registering) or updating(existing customer)?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe the event `customer_save_before`.
You will get the current customer as a parameter(somehow) and you can check if the customer has an id.

something like this:

```
public function doSomething($observer) {
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer(); 
    if ($customer->getId()) {
         //is update mode
    }
    else {
        //is create mode
    }
}
```